# Why does using read on a pipe hang when sending integers?

Tags: c, pipe, fork

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this code is hanging. It everything executes up until `read(pipe[1], &recieve, sizeof(int));` on the parent process.

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t fork(void);

int main(){
    pid_t main_pid = getpid();
    int fd[2];
    pid_t newproc = fork();
    pipe(fd);
    if (getpid() != main_pid){
        int send = 5;
        write(fd[1], &send, sizeof(int));
    }
    else{
        while (wait(NULL) > 0);
        int recieve;
        read(fd[0], &recieve, sizeof(int));
        printf("%d\n",recieve);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: `pid_t main_pid = getpid(); if ( getpid() != main_pid )` is better written as `if ( newproc == 0 )`

Comment: `while (wait(NULL) > 0);`. What's the point of this?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yields parent process until child process has exited

Comment: @A.J.Steinhauser That is what `wait` does.  I suppose the while loop might make sense if you have multiple children and want to (sloppily) wait for all of them to terminate, but with only one child the loop serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create two pipes.

The child writes to the pipe it created.

The parent reads from the completely unrelated pipe it created.

Since nothing was ever written the parent's pipe, reading from it blocks.

Swap the order of `fork` and `pipe`.

Answer (score 1):

You write

```
    pid_t newproc = fork();
    pipe(fd);
```

If you do the `pipe()` call *after* the `fork()` you end having two completely different pipes on parent and child (and unrelated to each other).  The pipe call must be done before the fork, so *both processes refer to the same pipe.*  In the way it is written above, neither the parent has access to the two descriptors the child has acquired, nor the child has access to the parent's.